# Move or clone an svg from lower div to top div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Trying to move a div from the chart_div to the movehere div.

I'm able to duplicate it below the current svg (commented code).
I'm also able to clone it but there is no easy way to target just the header row specifically. The 'g' element in that svg.

html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script><div id="movehere"><div id="chart_div"></div></div>
```

javascript

```
function afterDraw() {
    var g = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getElementsByTagName("g")[1];
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].parentNode.style.top = '40px';
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    var height = Number(g.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].getAttribute('y')) + 15;
    g.setAttribute('transform','translate(0,-'+height+')');
  g.setAttribute('transform','translate(0,-'+height+')');

  //var NewG=g.cloneNode(true)
 // var move="translate("+0+","+50+")"
//  NewG.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",move)
//  g.appendChild(NewG)

   $('#chart_div svg').clone().appendTo($('#movehere'))
    g = null;
  }
```

Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJzxzj

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your HTML code

Comment: When I uncomment `//$('.chart-div svg').clone()…` things appear to be working.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I don't know how your suggestion works since the wrong selector is being used in that line. `$('.chart-div svg').clone().appendTo($('.movehere'));` should be `$('#chart_div svg').clone().appendTo($('#movehere'));` The selector should  target **ID** `#` not **Class** `.` and  `chart-div` should be `chart_div`

Comment: @AndyHoffman thanks for pointing that out. I've tried a few things and forgot to update it. So the clone works sort of. Except I can't target just the header row. Currently the entire svg gets cloned.

Comment: @NewToJs Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, but how can I target the specific 'g' element in that svg (the header row)?

Comment: @JackBashford I added an example on codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/jormaturkenburg-the-typescripter/pen/QoVzBq

- I cleaned up your HTML in the pen.
- Commented out the CSS for now.
- Added an SVG element to move the g (group) to, you can't put SVG in a
  DIV you can only put it in an SVG-element.
- Added a translate to the g because the elements in that group are positioned with absolute coordinates and they are drawn pretty low and are therefore invisible in the smaller SVG-element.

```
    // The g you want has no id or class attached so selecting with
    // jQuery's n-th child selector was the easiest way to get it
    let group = $("#chart_div svg g:nth-child(3)");
    // Like I mention in my answer you need to attach the g to an SVG element, which I added to your div
    let targetSVG = $("#movehere svg");
    // To show the text you need to translate the group up by about 400 px
    group.clone().attr('transform', `translate(0 -400)`).appendTo(targetSVG);
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you check the id of the child in an svg object? I might need to do the same for the name column except clone it outside the div.

Comment: Inspect the source. Now right clicking on the object and clicking inspect is usually what you do but it is disabled on your chart so you have to dig around in the source by hand...